# Unable to save File to database from front end form in SilverStripe 4

Tags: silverstripe

I have a form that is posting data to a controller via ajax.

```
// Create new upload instance
$upload = Upload::create();

// Create new file instance
$file = File::create();

// Upload the file
$upload->loadIntoFile($fileData, $file, $this->folderName);

// Get the file from the Upload
$uploadedFile = $upload->getFile();

// Get the file from the Upload
$write = $uploadedFile->write();
```

The image is uploaded successfully but the File is not written to the Files table.

No errors are reported.

Comment: This might be better suited to the [SilverStripe issue tracker](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues) since 4.x is still in its alpha stage

Comment: @RobbieAverill Yeah, I thought it might have been something I was doing wrong, I tried this out on SS3 and the File is written correctly. I have logged a bug on the repo.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a pre-stable alpha release of SilverStripe 4

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with the file not being published? Did you check `File` vs. `File_Live` tables? Possibly related discussion: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/6048

Comment: Checked `File` and `File_Live`. `File` has around 9 entries and `File_Live` has around 90 so it looks like they are published. Also, how do I go about publishing files? I don't see an option for that anywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately file publish isn't implemented yet, it's on the list for our next alpha release: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-asset-admin/issues/169. For now, you'd need to call `File->publish('Stage', 'Live')` somewhere in your own code.